# .map() returns only the last object in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, local-storage

I am trying to use the browser's `localStorage` to store an `array` of objects. Each object have two `keys:` `name` and `quote`. Those values come from a `form` element.
When I reload the `browser`, I want to `map` through the array and display all the existing entries and when I add another one from the form element, to display that one as well.

I am using `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify` to convert the data to `string` and back again to an `array`.
I am using `document.createElement` and append it to the parent and `map` each object values in the `array` to the specific element.

When i `console.log` the array from `localStorage` after `JSON.parse` it looks like this:

```
[
{name: "sda", quote: "asd"}
{name: "fff", quote: "dsa"}
{name: "", quote: ""}
{name: "ferfe", quote: "fre"}
{name: "yhtyh", quote: "grtg"}
{name: "fdf", quote: "ds"}
{name: "fdf", quote: "ds"}
]
```

When I reload the browser and `map` the `array`, it returns only the last element from it and I dont't know why.

```
const process = () => {
    const getList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('key_name')).map(item => JSON.parse(item));
    console.log(getList)
    const cite = document.createElement('cite');
    const p = document.createElement('p');

    document.getElementById('quote_list').appendChild(cite);
    document.getElementById('quote_list').appendChild(p);

    return(
      getList.map(item => {
        cite.innerHTML = item.quote;
        p.innerHTML = item.name;
      })
    )
  }

  const setData = () => {
    let getList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('key_name'));
    const quote = document.quoteForm.quote.value;
    const name = document.quoteForm.name.value;
    const data = {name: name, quote: quote};
    const JsonData = JSON.stringify(data);
    localStorage.setItem('entry', JsonData);
    getList.push(JsonData);
    localStorage.setItem('key_name', JSON.stringify(getList));
    process();
  }

  window.addEventListener('onload', process());
```

If I add another entry from the form element it works just fine.
If I reload the browser it returns only the last item from the array.
`setData()` is triggered when I click the `submit button` of the `form`.

Comment: Why do you serialise and de-serialise twice?

Comment: What's the point of calling `JSON.parse()` on each item individually while you called `JSON.parse()` on the whole string in the beginning?

Comment: @mrJoe because the array is stored as a `string` `"["{}"]"` and the `objects` in it are `string` as well. When you call `JSON.parse` first time it returns an array with objects as a string `["{}"]`.

Comment: You probably made some mistake. `JSON.parse()` called once is enough to obtain JSON object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you overwrite the innerHTML of the 2 elements every iteration of `map()` loop and are left seeing only the last one

My guess is you would want new elements for each item

Try changing:

```
 getList.map(item => {
    cite.innerHTML = item.quote;
    p.innerHTML = item.name;
  })
```

To

```
const list = document.getElementById('quote_list');

getList.forEach(item => {
  const cite = document.createElement('cite');
  const p = document.createElement('p');
  cite.innerHTML = item.quote;
  p.innerHTML = item.name;
  list.appendChild(cite);
  list.appendChild(p)

})
```

---

Note: `window.addEventListener('onload', process());` should be:

```
window.addEventListener('onload', process);
                                  // ^^ function reference not 
                                  // result of calling function
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a variety of things I don't understand about your code:

1. `const getList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('key_name')).map(item => JSON.parse(item));` => why double-JSON.parse(), if you call JSON parse, the entire string is either parsed or an error is thrown, JSON.parse won't let any "leftovers", so the `JSON.parse()` within `.map()` and therefore the entire `.map()` is unnecessary as you simply return the already parsed object from `.map()`.
2. `getList.map(item => {` to render your HTML is probably not doing what you want it to do because a) `.map()` returns a new array from iterating over one, but you're not returning anything form this `.map()` call, so `process()` will return an empty array, doesn't really hurt, but could be improved by simply using `forEach()` for example.
3. The `cite` and `p` tags are only created once per call to `process`, not for each item within the quote list that you are getting from localStorage... so you are effectively overwriting the content of these two elements on each iteration.
4. Why are you setting `localStorage.setItem('entry', JsonData);` this localstorage entry does not seem to be used for anything?
5. You don't need to pre-stringify your new object with `const JsonData = JSON.stringify(data);`, you can simply push it to `getList` and then call `JSON.stringify()` on the new array of objects.
6. When adding the `onload` event listener, the function should be passed by reference

Considering above points, do you see any change in the behaviour if you use the following adapted code:

```js
  const process = () => {
    const getList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('key_name'));
    console.log(getList);

    getList.forEach(item => {
      const cite = document.createElement('cite');
      const p = document.createElement('p');

      document.getElementById('quote_list').appendChild(cite);
      document.getElementById('quote_list').appendChild(p);

      cite.innerHTML = item.quote;
      p.innerHTML = item.name;
    });
  }

  const setData = () => {
    let getList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('key_name'));
    const quote = document.quoteForm.quote.value;
    const name = document.quoteForm.name.value;
    const data = {name: name, quote: quote};
    getList.push(data);
    localStorage.setItem('key_name', JSON.stringify(getList));
    process();
  }

  window.addEventListener('onload', process);
```